# How do I pause for the specific time between two commands in a script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, timeout

I want to do something like following:

```
#!/bin/bash
command1
<pause for 30 seconds>
command2
exit
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use this in a terminal:

```
command1; sleep 30; command2
```

In your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
command1
sleep 30
command2
exit
```

Suffix for the sleep time:

- `s` for seconds (the default)
- `m` for minutes
- `h` for hours
- `d` for days

Answer (score 4):

You can use `read -t`. E.g:

```
read -p "Continuing in 5 seconds..." -t 5
echo "Continuing..."
```

In your script:

```
command1
read -p 'Pausing for 30 seconds' -t 30
command2
```

Note that you can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bypass the timeout period.